# Opening a modal from within an IFrame

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, modal-dialog

I am adding a modal/lightbox functionality to an image gallery. When the thumbnails are clicked, the main image is loading within an iframe.

Is it possible for any of the existing modal plugins to show the image outside this iframe, and within the window as a whole?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference `parent.window` so your modal is not confined to the iframe window.

Comment: Which plugin that you may know works? Can you provide an example?